# Sending voice input from frontend (html) to backend

Tags: python, html, browser, flask

I am trying to record voice from Chrome browser and have it sent to backend for converting it to text. I tried following articles:

1. http://codesamplez.com/programming/html5-web-speech-api
2. http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/
3. https://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

2nd link will give me following output when I speak 'What's your name'
`127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2016 03:08:30] "GET /dashboard?q=what%27s+your+name HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

This actually gives me speech to text.

However, I am stuck at trying to read the speech from browser. For backend I am using Python and Flask. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it after following 2nd link in question. I sent post request to the same handle and it could grab it. Thanks.